# Split a file based on required string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have test file with the below contents:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
CREATE TABLE XYZ_1 (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
```

Now I want to split this test single file into 2 files: one file with `CREATE` statement till `;`  as `file1` and the other file as `file2` with `REPLACE` statement till `;`.

Can you help me with how to split this, please?

Comment: Are these separated by \n s ? your previous post showed them all on the same line. Also, do you have "Similarly" in the input file ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed -n 'H                      # append every line to hold buffer
/CREATE\|REPLACE/h             # if CREATE or REPLACE, overwrite hold buffer
/;/{                           # if line matches ; then
x                              # exchange hold space w. pattern space
/CREATE/w file1                # if pattern space matches CREATE, write to file1
/REPLACE/w file2               # if it matches REPLACE, write it to file2
}
' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk` script:

```
/CREATE/{
b="";
    while (match($0, ";$")==0)
    {
        b=b $0"\n";
        getline;

    }
    b=b $0;
    print b > "file1";
}

/REPLACE/{
c="";
    while (match($0, ";$")==0)
    {
        c=c $0"\n";
        getline;

    }
    c=c $0;
    print c > "file2";
}
```

So

```
awk -f some.awk inputFile
```

produces:

```
cat file1
```

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);
CREATE TABLE XYZ_1 (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);
```

and

```
cat file2
```

```
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/CREATE/,/;/s/^//w file1' -e//d <infile >file2
```

... that just negates the range. It writes all of the lines within the *`CREATE ... ;`* span to file1 and all others to file2.

More simply, maybe:

```
sed -ne '/CREATE/,/;/w file1' -e '/REPLACE/,/;/w file2' <infile
```

...though that one might overlap if your actual input isnt as cut and dry as your example data.

With your example data, however, I can run either command and afterward do:

```
head -n50 file[12]
```

...to produce the following output:

```
==> file1 <==
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);
CREATE TABLE XYZ_1 (
ABC INT,
CDE CHAR(10),
.
.
.
);

==> file2 <==
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
Similarly, REPLACE VIEW XYZ (
ABC,
CDE,
EFG
);
```

Comment: @don_crissti - that's why i offered two - the best way, i think, would be both - only write to file2 after deleting lines which wrote to file1 *and* are within a replace block. divide and conquer?